# How to test this without mocks?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, automated-tests, tdd

I've been reading about testing without mocks and in general I like it. However, I've been struggling what to do when there's some third-party class included. For example if we have this class:

```
<?php

use External\ThirdPartyService;
use External\ThirdPartyException;

class AdapterForExternalService implements OurInterface
{
    private ThirdPartyService $external;

    public function __construct(ThirdPartyService $external)
    {
        $this->external = $external;
    }

    public function something(): int
    {
        try {
            return $this->external->someMethod();
        } catch (ThirdPartyException $e) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to test it by mocking the external class, but is it possible to do it without mocking too?

If mocking is non-avoidable here, what if the ThirdPartyService class is final?

Comment: Only a note for your example: You should mock your class (the method `something()`) and `disableConstructor()`. Mocking external classes seems very complex and not always doable (eg. final classes).

Comment: What do you mean by "You should mock your class"? I want to test my class?

Comment: Ok, its an very complex topic. For example is you randomize the return of the mocked external class, how can you test it? But when you are not randomize the outcome, why not directly mock your class, and have no dependencies in your tests to external classes? But i thing that can not really good discussed in an comment section. I prefer to write classes/apps that can on lowest level be mocked, so i dont need to mock external classes. But very very complex topic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `something()` method is not changing observable state. It only wraps the call to the third party service and turns the exception into an integer return value. The thing that is observable and that you could (in theory) assert on, is the call to the service and the returned results. This means, if you are not mocking, you will have to call that service.

To test this at all, you have to mock the dependency. If that class is really final, you can create a non-final facade for it and mock that.

Comment: Yes, when calling internal services, instead of mocking I create and provide a stub/fake implementation for a needed interface (eg. InMemoryUsersRepository instead of mock), but it is confusing to me how to avoid the call to the external service.

_"If that class is really final, you can create a non-final facade for it and mock that."_

Isn't this class in the example actually that "facade" you're talking about? Can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: Creating a "stub/fake" implementation is "mocking" as well. The term "mocking" is not bound to the usage of a mocking library.

Comment: Your simple example might be somewhat of a facade already, but it also contains logic (the exception handling. What I meant, is a simple wrapper, that is not adding any functionality.

Comment: It is hard to advise on this without knowing the real code in its real surroundings.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So the facade will be just the call to the external library without the try/catch block?

Comment: The short answer: Yes. The longer one: If your piece of code is really just an adapter with barely any logic, I would not test it at all, except maybe in an integration test.